# StandardStyles.xaml for WindowsPhone

Tags: windows-phone

When creating a Windows Store App from VS templates there is the Common/StandardStyles.xaml, including predefined styles, e.g. for buttons that look like the ones in the app bar. (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj841127.aspx))

Does anything like that exist for windows phone 7/8? For instance where do all those static resources like `PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my system they're installed in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Design
```

(and in the Dark and Light subfolders)

If you're looking for documentation on the builtin styles, [Microsoft has a good list here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552).